# Joomla custom php, form submits auto

Tags: php, forms, joomla, customization

I have a problem with Joomla custom module that I created. I have made form in one custom html module. Form calls action posting.php. Problem is that when I want to go on the with form, code is automatically executed, without me even seeing the page and I'm redirected to the page where I should be redirected if input is successful. DB is also populated with blank values. It seems to me like, form is automatically submitted when. How's that?

Is this common problem and I'm overlooking something or should I post some code :)

Comment: Why are you using a custom html module for this? Create a standard module and it will most likely solve your problem.

Comment: It was my mistake, I've put require_once for action php before html code in module. I thought I should call it that way, but all I had to do is to put entire url path in forms action attribute. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Please post an answer to this or delete it. It serves no purpose for other people.